# iPhone 6, iOS 11.1.2: Messages app closing right after I open it

Tags: iphone, ios, messages

I think I know when it appeared to be happening.  I had recieved some SMS text message from my bank regarding transaction item. And there was some special weird symbol, which looks like vise versa question mark.

I had something with macOS Notes, when I opened it and it just crashed.  So I just cleaned all content in Notes in iCloud web.  And was able to use macOS Notes again.

Is there any way I can clean all text messages in Messages app on iPhone?

I have removed everything, it seems in Settings -> iPhone Storage -> Messages:
[image: Messages Storage Desc]

But it keeps closing in right after I open it to write someone a reply. So basically I just can view notification previews and can't send a reply to anyone.

I have in mind some ways of fixing it. Like restore/refresh or wait for next iOS version to fix it or refresh it somehow.

Though, I don't want to restore the phone, settings or whatever. Might just probably wait when it cleans messages older than 30days of new iOS version will come up.

Comment: iOS 11.2 is out now. I'd update to that and see if it fixes the problem before trying anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS 11.2 did it. But what was the issue itself, who knows.